# What is the origin of horse brasses depicting sun, moon, star, and wheel?

Tags: folklore, origins

In England and other countries, many shire, cart and parade horses carry brasses, which often depict the sun, the crescent moon, a star, or a wheel. When did these designs first appear on horse brasses, and what were their lines of transmission to the present day?

Comment: @bleh Seems folkloric to me, but it's hard to tell without more context. The Earth: Can you provide links, pictures, etc. get more information?

Comment: It's folklore because it's expressive culture that has been passed down for centuries without using writing and that has many local and other variations. The (British) National Horse Brass Society has a [nice website](http://www.nationalhorsebrasssociety.org.uk) with photographs of many designs. The [Museum of Witchcraft and Magic's website](http://museumofwitchcraftandmagic.co.uk/object/horse-brass-amulet/) refers to the notion that the oldest types are those that feature "designs such as moons, suns and hearts". There's also [a Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horse_brass).

Answer (score 3):

[Thomas Hennell](https://books.google.be/books?id=h6PfHQhLmUcC&pg=PA22&lpg=PA22&dq=horse+brass+sun,+moon,+star,+wheel+origin&source=bl&ots=TYfdacUXkF&sig=JBxxOH6iGL8XKY1Sz06G8pkRRIY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiJo7iKjuTeAhWNZlAKHTpuClc4ChDoATADegQIBBAB#v=onepage&q=horse%20brass%20sun%2C%20moon%2C%20star%2C%20wheel%20origin&f=false) lists two possible origins:

Judges 8:21 & 8:26 (refers to camel ornaments)

or as protection against the evil eye.

In [Body Guards: Protective Amulets & Charms](https://books.google.be/books?id=VdTtAAAAMAAJ):

> FOR THOUSANDS OF years the horse was the key to human mobility, and
>   this made it a precious possession that ... The images used included
>   suns, crescent moons, hearts and lotus-flowers, evoking the sun-god,
>   the moon- goddess and the gods of ancient Egypt. ... in its role
>   representing the sun moving through the heavens, sacred hands, stars,
>   wheels and horns. ... The simple idea was that, if the Evil One looked
>   up at the The sun-flash horse-brass that swings back and forth.

In [Apollo](https://books.google.be/books?id=Et5GAQAAIAAJ):

> the following, therefore, some of the most common designs found in
>   horse brasses are accounted for. The belief in ... Thus for centuries
>   these charms and amulets were used in all countries, and took the form
>   of the moon or crescent, the wheel, lion, dog, serpent, &c. In Turkey
>   the ... Some show the face of the sun surrounded by rays, more
>   commonly we find some form of radiating device. Many appear like
>   Stars, roses, or merely patterns which are degenerate forms of solar
>   origin.